# Supply white/blue led with 3V3 at constant current

Tags: voltage, led, diodes

I need to drive a white/blue led at low constant current (about 10mA.)

To do that I usually use the schematic below, but in my case I can only supply the LED with 3V3.

Since the typical forward voltage of white leds @10mA ranges from 2.7V to 3V, the voltage drop across R2 could range from about 0.5V to 0.3V.

For tolerance reasons I'm afraid that with this variability I cannot guaranteed a repeatable luminous flux with different leds.

Can you suggest to me a different way to drive a led that can control the resistance?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2focmNH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Can the ON/OFF signal not sink the LED current directly? What is it? Is the circuit battery powered or mains? Are you sure Y is base to GND and not in between ON/OFF and the base?

Comment: Your concern is more than valid. You can't get any repeatable luminous flux when you operate on the margins on everything. And consider a variable temperature as well. And supply variability.

Comment: And how "repeatable" do you want your luminous flux to be?

Comment: stupid question: Where your 3.3V comes from, is there some higher-voltage rail also available? Because if it is, you could build a sub-1€ switch mode const current power supply from that.

Answer (score 3):

The following *might* work with the compensation cap and resistors set to zero (i.e., no C1, wires for R3 and R4), but only if you choose an op-amp that is designed to drive capacitive loads, and a FET that has a particularly low-capacitance gate.

In addition to gate capacitance, your FET also needs to be "logic level", and should probably be rated for a 3.3V gate voltage.

The component count is distressingly high, but you should be able to get away with cheap parts.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flE7Nf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Why is this circuit not available as a standard CCR?  I have tried parts like the On-Semi  NSI50010YT1G but the required voltage overhead (Vak) is too high for a low voltage source.   What I currently do is match the Vf with a corresponding resistor.   value or use an LM3414 LED driver.   I would like to find a low Vak CCR.

Comment: I don't know!  It'd sure be nice!

Answer (score 1):

To drive an LED with constant current, given that the LED may have both
manufacturing and temperature dependence in its terminal voltage, you
want a very high impedance drive.   To use a low voltage (3.3V) source, 
and attain a given current, a simple high-value resistor does not
fill the need.   This is one way to do it (a current mirror):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fR9JJH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The nominal 0.6V base-emitter drop, and R1, make a circa 10mA current in Q2,
and the (matched) Q1 has a relatively high collector impedance, with
similar current.   Matched-pair transistors, packaged together to 
have the same temperature of operation, are available for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

There's slightly more advanced constant current sinks (or sources) than your single BJT plus resistor could be; these could be built with lower effective output resistance (and thus, a lower output voltage drop than the inevitable 0.7 V that you'll get here, at least). For example, a self-biased JFET might do that – and they even come in handy small packages, e.g. for [15 mA](https://www.onsemi.com/PowerSolutions/product.do?id=NSI45015W).

However, even that device would require a headroom of about 0.5 V.

So, if you really need full forward voltage headroom, and have a lot of LEDs in parallel to drive, anyways, designing a boost (or inverting) power supply interestingly becomes a viable option – in the simplest case, one supply for all your LEDs to give you e.g. 4.2 V, so that a simple biased transistor regulator works. Doing such a design, e.g. with TI's webbench power designer (ti.com) is actually not very hard, and there's probably even a module that you can simply buy that does what you need.

In a more advanced case, if you really need the reliable luminosity: there's plenty of multi-channel LED drivers; and they support things like telling them brightness correction values for individual LED channels. Look at TI's and Maxim's and ON Semi's websites.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot make use of any dcdc converter or led driver for both efficiency and mainly cost reasons. I have to only drive two leds indipendentely for a touch human interface.

Comment: I was thinking to use some kind of current mirror with mosfet... thank you anyway :)

Comment: um, there's nothing to win in efficiency here, sorry.

Comment: If you could find well-enough matched MOSFETs your current mirror may work.  You'll be on an adventure with both you and purchasing, though.

Comment: @TimWescott you mean a pair like [this](https://eu.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Advanced-Linear-Devices/ALD212902SAL?qs=sGAEpiMZZMshyDBzk1%2FWiwR5CZlvOXdbVcaulXt2eRgzp5uXJ3JVsw%3D%3D) one?

Comment: @PaulLake efficiency consideration would actually suggest the optimum solution was a current-mode switch-mode power supply – not hard to build, per se, but in this case where V_out is approximately V_in, you'd need a little more than the most basic boost architectures, if you really want to be efficient. It'd still not be significantly more complex than Tim's answer (no offense, Tim!).

Answer (score 0):

I highly doubt the human eye could distinguish the difference in illuminance.  The eye's pupil will moderate the perceived brightness much more than the LED's V<sub>f</sub>.

I would suggest using a newer Cree LED (e.g. XP-G3) which will have a low enough V<sub>f</sub> (i.e. less than 2.7 V) to regulate the current with an FET.

When a datasheet specifies 2.7-3.0 V<sub>f</sub>, that is typically over the full current range of the LED.  At 10 mA you should be able to easily find an LED with a V<sub>f</sub> less than 2.7 V.  There may be an LED with the required illuminance at a much lower current (e.g. less than 1 mA), and consequently a lower V<sub>f</sub>.